# Calling a global function in another JS file. How do I get 'this' to work?

Tags: javascript, this, global

I have 2 js files:

file1.js contains prototype A with:

```
printname: function() {
   console.log('my name is A');
}

getname: function() {
    console.log('getting name..');
    this.printname();
}
```

Then I put 'getname' function in a global variable because I want to access it anywhere:

```
globalvar.myfunction = this.getname;
```

file2.js contains prototype B with:

```
runmyglobalfunction: function() {
   globalvar.myfunction();
}
```

When I call this.runmyglobalfunction, the result is:

I can see console log 'getting name..'.

But I can't see 'my name is A'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function's `this` value to a specific value:

```
globalvar.myfunction = this.getname.bind(this);
```

Now, no matter how `globalvar.myfunction` is called, `this` inside the function will always refer to what `this` referred to in that line.

Related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)